# calling awk script from C++ stops at "bozo :wait_for"

Tags: c++, awk

I am calling a bash script from C++ by first doing a `vfork()`, and then calling `execv(SHELLPATH, SHELLSCRIPT)`. From the bash script, I then call an awk script to process the output of a command, using:

```
cat textfile | ./parseInfo.awk
```

I notice that the bash script runs fine, but when it gets to the awk script, it just hangs and has the command-line response: `"awk: bozo: wait_for"`. I haven't been able to find a reference on google to what this response could mean.

After doing some prints from the awk script, I noticed that when I do a system() call, that is what is causing this waiting from the script (which I then need to press enter on in order to get back the command-line prompt). So what I'm doing is:

```
dirNotExistCheck = "[ -d " DIR "]"
if(system(dirExistCheck) == 1)
{

}
```

Is there a way to call sysem() without needing some kind of interaction from the user?

Comment: It appears to be waiting for some clown...

Comment: And what happens if you run this outside of the C++ code? Note that `cat file | awkScript` can almost always be simplified to `awkScript file`. This may be part of your problem. In any case, determine if is just the awk program that is the problem, or that you have it nested so deeply. Good luck.

Comment: It's very interesting that the return code for system(dirExistCheck) was -1 when I ran this as a gawk script. What I eventually did was to run this again as an awk script (/usr/bin/awk) and then instead of doing the check for the existence of the directory the way I mentioned in my original post, I used system("mkdir -p" DIR) - this will not make the directory if it already exists. At any rate, I was able to finally get it working, but it is still a mystery to me as to what this "wait_for" response from awk was. @shelter - thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If it is waiting for a key to be hit, you can run it like this `echo | <your command here>`

We are just making *your command* to read its input from another place. Hope this helps...